# How to Equally distribute the data point on the graph along x axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have some datas, say from [0.1:0.1:0.9]+[1:1:10].

If I use scatter to plot it, it looks like this.

[image]

However, it want the points equally distribute along the axis, anyone can tell me how to do it? What I mean is the distance between data points in [0.1-0.9] are the same with [1-10] on the graph respect to x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is contained in vectors `x` and `y`, use

```
plot(y,'o')
```

instead of `plot(x,y,'o')` or `scatter(x,y)`.

If you want to label the `x` axis, use something like

```
set(gca,'xtick',1:length(y),'xticklabel',[.1:.1:.9 1:10])
```

Or you might want a subset of the labels, for example:

```
set(gca,'xtick',1:2:length(y),'xticklabel',[.1:.2:.9 2:2:10])
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! But if I only want to show, say [0.1 0.5 1 5] label along x-axis, then how to change the set(...) content? In addition, could you explain the above magic a little bit :)

Comment: @AllenJee I updated my answer. For those labels you use `set(gca,'xtick',[1 5 10 14],'xticklabel',[.1 .5 1 5])`. The first vector selects a subset of values of the x axis and sets ticks at those points; and the second vector specifies the labels for those ticks

Comment: @AllenJee The line `plot(y,'o')` simply plots the data `y` assuming the x axis is 1, 2, 3... You then set the x axis ticks and labels with the line `set(...)`